# Is there a way to change the name of a Start menu link name using a Custom Action

Tags: windows-installer, startmenu

We are localizing our application and need to change the name displayed in the Start menu based on the current UI culture.  We would like to do this using a Custom Action during the installation.  We are using Windows Installer deployment projects and do not plan on using any third party deployment tools.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A CustomAction cannot modify the contents of a database (it is read-only while executing).  You'd have to take over the entire creation of the shortcut.  I would recommend a better Windows Installer creation tool before doing that since you'll need to write a lot of code to handle the rollback scenarios for instal and uninstall plus reference counting.

There are better tools out there than the Visual Studio deployment projects. Some like the [WiX toolset](http://wix.sourceforge.net) are free (fully featured but more work).